# Cannot resolve class TextView

Tags: android, textview

I am a complete newbie on Android Studio, and I'm trying to code some things, but I'm still blocked by a simple thing : in an xml file, I have this : (https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKhO6.png)

I still can't figure out how to fix this error.

I tried all the solutions suggested on other relative topics but none of them worked for me. I would be very grateful if someone can help me out and solve this thing which made me lose my motivation :(

Answer (score 0):

Don't lose motivation! You will always face this kind of problemas and you will resolve them!

This looks like a Gradle problem. Try upgrading all libraries to last version.

Also you can try to invalidate cache and restart Android Studio!

Let us know if it worked, and keep it up!

Comment: Hi Rodrigo, thank you very much for your answer and your kind words. I tried updating all libraries (File>Settings>Appearance&Behavior>System Settings>Updates) and invalidated cache and restart, I still have the same problem...

Comment: Edit: I'm now having the error "Element TextView not allowed here". What should I do ?

Comment: Try adding  implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4' to your Gradle

Comment: By the way I just saw that you have written "androiddx", and its androidx